# Looking for peach preserves substitute

Tags: substitutions, sauce, allergy, jelly, peaches

I'm making a dish that that has a "sweet and sour" sauce to it.  The recipe calls for apricot and peach preserves.  Unfortunately I am highly allergic to peaches.  Does any one know what a good substitute would be?  Could I just use Apricot alone and double the amount needed?   It is being served with an Asian style chicken and vegetables over rice if that helps.  As I can't eat the peaches I don't know what would be best to match the flavor profile.

Comment: Hey, can you link to an online recipe which is like the recipe you're trying to create? Having a clear idea of the whole recipe will help folks with suggestion substitutions.

Comment: The recipe is out of a cookbook but I can copy it for you -

Comment: Sauce-
1/4 cup peach preserves
1/4 cup apricot preserves
2 TBS light corn syrup
5 tsp white vinegar
1 1/2 tsp cornstarch
1/2 tsp soy sauce
1/2 tsp yellow mustard
1/4 tsp salt
1/8 tsp garlic powder
2 TBS water

1. Combine all ingredients except the water in a food processor or a blender and puree until the mixture is smooth. 

2. Pour the mixture into a small saucepan over medium heat. Add the water, stir, and bring mixture to a boil. Allow it to boil for five minutes, stirring often. When the sauce has thickened, remove it from the heat and let it cool.

Answer (score 4):

Apricots ([Prunus armeniaca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prunus_armeniaca) and peaches ([Prunus persica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peach)) are botanically speaking “close cousins” and have a quite similar flavor profile. Fresh apricot tends to be both sweeter and tarter, peach is a bit milder overall. The difference is less pronounced with preserves.

For your sauce, apricot alone (i.e. using more apricot to get the same amount as the original apricot + peach) should be perfectly fine, assuming that you will adjust the sweet and sour other ingredients and seasonings to your liking anyway.

If you find that apricot alone is too intense (unlikely, but of course there is no accounting for taste), I suggest some very mild fruit, e.g. pear or a sweet apple.